# How to determine if a column already exists in a MySQL table before altering the table to add it?

Tags: mysql, php, ddl

I am trying to determine if a column already exists in a MySQL table before altering the table to add it. I need an all in one query I can run since I am executing this through an old PHP mysql library that only executes a single statement in one call. This the query I was attempting to use.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as col_count
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'status';
```

Unfortunately the DATABASE() function returns information_schema instead of current connection DB at least in PHPMyAdmin. It may be different through the PHP mysql driver. Therefore, it returns zero for the column count.

```
SELECT DATABASE(), COUNT(*) as col_count
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'status';
```

This returns: "Information_schema", "0" despite the fact that the original connection was to a different database.

I have come up with a workaround in PHP but would still like to know if this is possible using only SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.  Add one thing before your code:

```
USE YourDb;  -- You need to be in _your_ db to make `DATABASE()` work right

SELECT COUNT(*) as col_count
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
      AND  TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
      AND  COLUMN_NAME = 'status';
```

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify that I need an all in one query I can run since I am executing this through an old PHP mysql library that only executes a single statement in one call. I can't run two statements together. The PHP mysql connection is NOT to information_schema, it is to "YourDb" say.

Comment: If the default db is already `YourDb`, then only the `SELECT` is needed.  I added the `USE` because you were obviously having some kind of trouble in that area when you got back `information_schema, 0`.

Comment: Not sure why it wasn't working through that old PHP library back then but the single query in my post works fine in MySQL Workbench now. Marking as the accepted answer since the "USE yourdb" part could be useful to other people looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `DESCRIBE table_name` to print the table definition

Comment: Can you more fully explain how this solves the OP's problem? I'm no MySQL expert but it seems like this is going to result in a lot of string parsing in PHP. I believe the OP would rather have SQL that will detect the column and conditionally create the column if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually, this isn't a terrible option. The result set from `DESCRIBE table_name` can simply be looped through in PHP to look for the column.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just `ALTER TABLE` and catch the error related to a existing column already there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119566)

Comment: Apologies, the question half implied a check before doing an alter. Was a 2 year old post so was just leaving as an alternate strategy for migrations for those that search this question.